# Execute a line of PHP before Ajax submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a function in WordPress that handles the uploading of files to the WordPress image gallery. After converting the form to Ajax, I realized the file upload no longer works.  The thing is, if I could just get the function to execute before the Ajax it would work.  Here is the code:

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
        return __return_false(); 
    }
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    if ($setthumb) 
        update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
    return $attach_id;
}
```

and here is the call that I want to execute before the Ajax submission is called:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) 
{
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post_id); 
}
```

The reason is that `$newupload` sends the file to the wordpress image gallery, and then returns the `attachmentID` for insertion into the same table the Ajax is inserting into.  So if the code could just run before the Ajax, it would work fine.  Is this possible at all?

How to run a PHP function in the background on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP runs on server not on client so the thing you asking is possible only on server.

So do an ajax call complete that on server and in callback use another ajax call.

CAll ajax1 --> callback --> call ajax2

Like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    data: {name: 'xxxxxx'},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){

        // do stuff

        // call next ajax function
        $.ajax({ xxx });
    }
});
```

Comment: how can I do that without the user pressing the button twice?

Comment: See above example call first ajax on button click.